# Google autocomplete address dropdown not comes in its respective input field. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, vue.js

I tried to fix google map location inside bootstrap modal. When click on input field location dropdown comes with another input field. I googled but I did not found any solution.

```
     function initialize() {
                var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}, types: \['geocode'\]}
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), options);
        }

      initialize();
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Hi @Purnima Sh, So you want to hide the displayed list of the address shown in the image. And the address list comes only in a dropdown box.

Comment: Can you share your html code? maybe there is a mistake in the id or something.

Comment: Actually there is a  location field. I want to show google location dropdown with the location input but dropdown show one step below the input.